# Identify wiring in light switch

Tags: wiring, smart-switch

I wanted to buy a smart light switch but I wanted to make sure I have all the necessary wires to do so before buying it. I need to know if I have the neutral wire. There are two switches one to control the fan and the other to control light attached to the fan. Any help in telling which wires I have would be much appreciated.

[image: Wiring]

[image: Wiring]

Comment: Looks like no neutral.  White wire has black tape on it saying it is used as a hot wire.  Would need to run a new /3 cable to have neutral wire(required in new code now).

Comment: Okay, yeah that is kind of what I thought, but wanted to double check! Thanks for the help! I really appreciate it!! @crip659

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like no neutral.  White wire has black tape on it saying it is used as a hot wire.  Would need to run a new /3 cable to have neutral wire(required in new code now).  You only have hot and switch hot wires

Comment: They probably should run a /4 cable even; that'd let them consolidate the two /2s into the same cable